# how to change the properties of excel column before exporting procedure from ms access?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, properties

I'm currently exporting a procedure from ms access to excel with a click of a button. However I would like to change the properties of the date column to display it as type "dd/mm/yyy hh:mm" instead of the default "dd-mm-yy". Is there any way of doing this within the vba code of access? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
'<< Your existing code to export query to Excel >>

Dim xl As Object  'the Excel Application

On Error Resume Next
'Attempt to use an existing instance of Excel
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error Goto 0  'Restore appropriate ErrorHandler here
    'Create new instance of Excel
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Else
    On Error Goto 0  'Restore appropriate ErrorHandler here
End If

Dim wb As Object  'the Excel Workbook object
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FullPathToExcelWorkbook)

Dim ws As Object  'the Excel Worksheet object
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

Dim col As Object  'the Column whose data type you want to change
Dim FieldName As String  'the name of the query's field to change
FieldName = "MyDateAndTimeColumn"
Set col = ws.Columns(ws.Cells.Find(FieldName).Column)

col.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
```

You'll obviously need to add appropriate error handling (e.g., the Excel file may already be open, etc.), but this should get you going.  Also, I used late-binding here to allow maximum compatibility with different versions of Excel.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, I have some questions though. What do I enter instead of "Excel.Application". And what should I enter instead of FullPathToExcelWorkbook? Also I think I should mention the only code I have before this is  DoCmd.OutputTo acStoredProcedure, "usp_procedure", "MicrosoftExcel(*.xls)", "test.xls", False, ""  Is this the correct way to export with your method?

Comment: You would use `"Excel.Application"` as is.  As for `FullPathToExcelWorkbook`, that would be the "test.xls" parameter from the sample code in your comment.  However, I would strongly advise you to use a full path there, otherwise the code will put "test.xls" into whatever the current working directory is (which could change during the life of your application).

Comment: Thank you this works great. However at the moment the excel sheet is open after the columns change even though it's not physically open? is there a way of closing the excel application after the column change is made?

Comment: Nevermind, I found doing this works: xl.Workbooks(1).Save xl.Workbooks(1).Close SaveChanges:=True. Any idea how to add another query to this workbook in a seperate sheet? i've tried acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9 but i get error 7874 cannot find object (my other query)

Comment: If you are using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet then just call the command on the same Excel file and it will add a new worksheet automatically.  From the TransferSpreadsheet action help page, "*Microsoft Access creates a new spreadsheet when you export data from Microsoft Access. If the file name is the same as the name of an existing spreadsheet, Microsoft Access replaces the existing spreadsheet, unless you're exporting to a Microsoft Excel version 5.0, 7.0, 8.0 or Excel 2000 workbook. In that case, Microsoft Access copies the exported data to the next available new worksheet in the workbook.*"

Comment: Here's the link to the help file I referenced above: [TransferSpreadsheet Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164087(v=office.10).aspx).  And also this: [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method (Access)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx)